# Как при определенном событии обновить таблицу стилей

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как средствами js/jquery, при определенном событии обновить таблицу стилей.

Не перезагрузить страницу целиком, а просто обновить таблицу стилей.

Понимаю, что вопрос довольно странный, но ... такая задача ...

Answer (score 2):

Либо создать элемент `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%нужный%" title="....">` и поместить его в head, либо у уже существующего стиля подменить href. Должно сработать.

Comment: @SoWa, спасибо. Есть еще у кого-нибудь варианты?

Comment: @Astor, можно обновлять число после вопросительного знака (/style.css?123), и стили без перезагрузки страницы изменяться.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю, если нужно обновить существующий css, то достаточно добавить в конец адреса css-файла знак вопроса и случайное число. Например href="css/style.css?96"